# Blue Ocean - 'Repository URL - Please enter a valid URL' error

Tags: jenkins, url, local, jenkins-blueocean

I'm trying to make a Pipeline in Blue Ocean. I want to use a **local repo** but whatever I enter in the text field I get the error **'Repository URL - Please enter a valid URL'**

I've tried

```
/home/ustrd/IdeaProjects/tutorial_ranking/.git/
/home/ustrd/IdeaProjects/tutorial_ranking/.git
file:///home/ustrd/IdeaProjects/tutorial_ranking/.git/
file:///home/ustrd/IdeaProjects/tutorial_ranking/.git
```

following the information on a Jenkins official page:

*If your URL is a local directory path (e.g. beginning with a forward slash / such as /home/cloned-git-repos/my-git-repo.git), you can proceed to click the Create Pipeline button.* https://jenkins.io/doc/book/blueocean/creating-pipelines/

Does it have something to do with the fact that I run Jenkins from a Docker container? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found it: remove the username from the path ('ustrd' in my case) & remove '.git'

```
/home/IdeaProjects/tutorial_ranking
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enough space on your system to run jenkins. If that is not the case create space by deleting jenkins logs and unused images, and then restart your systems.